# Entity Framework - recursively find all descendant categories

Tags: c#, recursion, entity-framework-core, tree

I have a Category class (representing game genres) where each category can have zero or one parent category and zero to many child categories.  I'm trying to write a recursive method that finds all categories below a given category, branching out all the way down the tree.

The code below (from my CategoriesController.cs) only adds the first category at each level; seemingly never coming back to the next category in the foreach at any level.  Where am I going wrong?

```
    // GET: Categories/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {   
        // get the category from id, and include parent and child categories
        var category = await _context.Categories
            .Include(c => c.ParentCategory)
            .Include(c => c.ChildCategories)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        
        List<Category> descendantCategories = new();
        descendantCategories = await GetDescendantCategories(category, descendantCategories);
        
        ViewBag.Breadcrumbs = new BreadcrumbTrail(_context, category);
        ViewBag.Descendants = descendantCategories;

        return View(category);
    }

    private async Task<List<Category>> GetDescendantCategories(Category category, List<Category> descendants)
    {
        if (category.ChildCategories != null && category.ChildCategories.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (Category child in category.ChildCategories)
            {
                var addChild = await _context.Categories
                    .Include(c => c.ChildCategories)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == child.ID);
                descendants.Add(addChild);
                return await GetDescendantCategories(addChild, descendants);                    
            }
        }

        if (descendants is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(descendants));
        }

        return descendants;
    }
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code?

Comment: Better to create View or Stored procedure which using recursive CTE returns plain list of all categories of the leaf. Then build tree on the client side.

Comment: what db are you using? .NET 6 EF for postgres supports `ltree` data type which would be ideal for your situation. Maybe other dbs have smth similar as well, I don't know. If not, then you really should write a function/procedure/view instead of trying to write it in c#.